# Interpreting/Reporting means for a MANCOVA

Tags: mancova

I did a study on whether people have a chronic illness (dichotomous variable, 1 or 0) and several measures of psychological well-being. Two questions:

1.) Does one report the means of the raw scores (summed scores for each scale), transformed means (some, but not all, scales were skewed and transformed by log or sqrt so as to not violate the assumption of normal distribution)? The analyses were done with the transformed means for the transformed variables (although it was significant with the raw scores as well). The raw scores seem more interpretable, but the transformed scores were used in the actual analysis

2.) The issue I'm having also is that, in one study, the difference between the means (either raw or transformed) are not different in some cases, that is until the MANCOVA controls for age & sex, and the differences become significant. It does make logical sense to control for age & sex since chronic illness is related to both (in this sample and others). In other words, it would seem discordant to report means that do not differ, but MANCOVA results that show they clearly differ (small to large partial eta squared).

Thanks.